# How to pass textarea

Tags: php, textarea

I am trying to pass

```
echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea>'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
```

from this while loop

```
    echo '<table border=0>';
    while ($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getedit))
        {
            echo '<form method="POST" action="">';

            echo '<tr><td>Sr.No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['SRNO'].' name="SRNO" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['fname'].' name="fname"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['lname'].' name="lname"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['phone'].' name="phone"></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['email'].' name="email"</td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea>'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td><td></td></tr>';
            echo '</form>';                                 
        }
    echo '</table>';
```

but I get an error. Other table rows get passed well...

The complete code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List of users</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php
        $page='index.php';  

        mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("list") or die (mysql_error());

        if (empty($_POST) === false)
        {

            $fname= $_POST['fname'];
            $srno=  $_POST['SRNO'];



            mysql_query('update names set fname="'.$fname.'" where SRNO="'.$srno.'"');  

            header('Location:'.$page);
        }


        if(isset($_GET['edit']))
        {
            $getedit=mysql_query('SELECT SRNO, fname, lname, phone, email from names where SRNO='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['edit']));

            echo '<table border=0>';
            while ($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getedit))
                {
                    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';

                    echo '<tr><td>Sr.No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['SRNO'].' name="SRNO" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['fname'].' name="fname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['lname'].' name="lname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['phone'].' name="phone"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['email'].' name="email"</td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea>'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td><td></td></tr>';
                    echo '</form>';                                 
                }
            echo '</table>';

        }

        $get=mysql_query('SELECT  SRNO, fname, lname, email, phone, address, comments from names ORDER BY SRNO ASC');

        if (mysql_num_rows($get)==0)
        {
            echo 'There are no entries';
        }
            else
        {
            echo '<table border=0 cellspacing=25 cellpadding=1>';
            echo'<tr><th>Sr. No</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone No</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Address</th><th>Comments!!</th><th>Modify</th></tr>';      
            while($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
                {
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$get_row['SRNO'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['fname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['lname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['phone'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['email'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['address'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['comments'].'</td><td><a href="index.php?edit='.$get_row['SRNO'].'">Edit</a></td></tr>';

                }
            echo '</table>';
        }       
    ?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get? We can't really tell you why it's happening if we don't know what it is.

Comment: You didnt put address in the select clause

Comment: Oh Yes.... I did not select it... After selecting it in the query itself it worked...Many Thanks Sinan!!!!

Comment: put the `FORM` tags BEFORE the `TABLE` tag. Perhaps it will not solve your problem, but i have the experience that this is better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the names you want to use in the while statement in to the SELECT clause.

Add address to your SELECT:

```
SELECT address, SRNO, fname, lname, phone, email from names where SRNO='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['edit'])
```